# Auto Complete and content assist will not shut off (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, autocomplete

> Hello, I have spent over an hour attempting to disable ALL
>   auto-complete and suggestions in the Android SDK in Eclipse. Android
>   uses both XML and Java files. Currently I have been working on XML
>   files and every time I reach an end of line I hit [Enter], but there
>   is an auto-complete dialogue up and it prints "style" at the end of
>   the line.
>
> Any assistance would be great, I have been searching online and have
>   been turning EVERYTHING off in: Windows -> Preferences -> Java ->
>   Editor Windows -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor
>
> While I finally got closing tags and quotes from popping up, this
>   irritating and downright WRONG auto-complete keeps popping up.
>
> If there is some overall disable switch that I am missing I will feel
>   stupid, but would be grateful for the assistance.
>
> Thanks for all your assistance.

Hello All!

I am working in Eclipse with Java and XML doing Android app development.

The above quoted text is the exact same issue I'm having. Unfortunately this was posted in a forum January of 2011 and received no replies which makes me wonder if this issue is a bug that hadn't been fixed. I have tried using *Eclipse 3.6.2, 3.7.2, SR2,* and as also said above, I have disabled all options related to auto completion or content assist, in every platform listed in Eclipse, Java, XML, etc... I have spent about two days messing with all manner of settings and researching online how to solve this problem.

The general advice in other forums, with the same problem, not just XML, is almost always to go `Window->preferences->[platform]->Editor->Content Assist (and/or) Typing` and disable the relevant options. Half the people claim it fixes their problem, while the other half claim it does not. I happen to be in the "does not" crowd as everything I've tried has no effect, even after shutting down and restarting *Eclipse*, the content assist and code completion options are all still disabled yet it continues to happen. I'm starting to get desperate as this is really cramping my coding style.

Is this a bug? Or am I just missing something? Thank you!

[image: Screen shot of said issue]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/531730_481454708550536_866774212_n.jpg))</sub>

The automatic insertion of "style=" appears to be the result of the suggestion box being triggered right after I type the closing quote on wrap_content. The reason it's the keyword "style" inserted after pressing enter is because it's the first item on the list. I'm not sure if the "suggestion box" is content assist or not.

[image]

I have tried to disable content assist as shown below. But it contingues to give me the popup suggestion box when trigger characters are typed.

[image]

Any insight and/or help on this would be so much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the problem? I think that would help everyone understand more clearly what you're experiencing.

Comment: You can upload the screenshot on a free uploading website and include the link.

Comment: It's not allowing me to post a screen shot because I don't have enough reputation points. Is there a work around for this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing nobody know's about this matter?

Comment: As it turns out, it appears that you have restart the editor for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong. It still gives content assist in xml files even after I disabled the settings and restarted eclipse.